# Construction of an integral point set given the set of distances, its minimal description to get a measure of its complexity and its unique identifier

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, algorithms, computational-complexity, discrete-geometry, computational-geometry

Given a set of distances between every pair of points   of an  integral point set $P$ of $n$ points; say $D = \{{d_i}\}$.

> **Q1.** What is the least time complexity
>   possible/known for recreating the
>   Integral point set $P$  given $D$ through
>   a Turing machine computable
>   algorithm?
>
> **Q2.**  **What is the shortest string which
>   can describe $P$?**

For example:

- Using $D$ to describe $P$ may  be a shorter method than $P$ itself;
- Scaling $D$ down to elements  all relatively prime may still shorten the description string.
- Using a certain set of computed values  to describe $P$ may further minimize the expression ( provided they exist).
- Just $P= \text{IntegralPointSet}(n)$ will be problematic as

  - It is not Turing computable. (Comments?)
  - It does not define exactly the point set we want out of possibly many such integral point sets.

Which gets me to the third question:

> **Q3.** What is the *shortest string required to uniquely identify a
>   particular  integral point set of
>   cardinality $n$*  amongst all other such
>   integral  point sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a direct answer, but rather an historical, and somewhat tangential comment. Back in 1979, the general problem you posed was proved NP-hard by Saxe and by Yemini independently. There has been quite a rich literature on this topic in the last 35+ years, which you might trace via Google Scholar.
*Added*. For example, see the 2014 survey below.

> James B. Saxe. Embeddability of weighted graphs in k-space is strongly NP-hard. In *Proceedings of the 17th Allerton Conference on Communications, Control, and Computing*, pp. 480–489, 1979. Also in James B. Saxe: Two Papers on Graph Embedding Problems, Department of Computer Science, Carnegie-Mellon University, 1980. ([PDF download](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~dpt/RigidityREU/Saxe79EmbedNPHard.pdf).)
>
> Yechiam Yemini. Some theoretical aspects of position-location problems. In *20th Annual Symposium on Foundations of Computer Science (FOCS)*, pp. 1–8, Oct. 1979. DOI: 10.1109/SFCS.1979.39
>   ([ACM link](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1382599).)
>
> Liberti, Leo, Carlile Lavor, Nelson Maculan, and Antonio Mucherino. "Euclidean distance geometry and applications." *Siam Review* 56(1) (2014): 3-69.
>   ([Journal link](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/120875909?journalCode=siread).)

[image: H16]

          

<sub>(Figure from "Untangling planar graphs from a specified vertex position—Hard cases" ([Elsevier link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X11000230)).)</sub>